# Clearing IE cache remotely

Tags: html, caching, browser

We recently went live with a new a CMS solution. However we didn't realise that by default this solution does not add a no-cache header, etc. to HTML pages.

Whilst we have now fixed this, our visitors using IE especially have a cache of the bulk of our HTML pages (including references to old CSS and JS files).

Is there a way of cache busting for those users who visited the site in the first month post go-live? As I'm worried that we can't successfully move forward with our design and JS functionality because of people with an old cached version.

Comment: any particular versions or all?

Comment: I'm at least concerned with IE7 and 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do requests to the page normally return a `Last-Modified` header?  That's the only reliable way to bust caches I have any experience with.

Most browsers will send an `If-Unmodified-Since` request header if they're caching something (unless the default caching behavior on this CMS was to set an explicit cache expiry date, which would be extremely unusual).  So, all you'd have to do is emit a `Last-Modified:[date you added no-cache headers]` header in the response, and a correctly behaving HTTP server would send clients the full updated HTML page.

[Correct format can be found in the HTTP protocol.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Although not exactly my problem, it did get me thinking - I found that my problem was that my `Cache-Control` header was set to `no-cache`... the problem is that both our offices (and the majority of our client-base) are behind proxies - I simply changed `Cache-Control` to `private, max-age=0`. We've also got `Expires` as `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a central URL generation function, track it down and always append `?_version=2` (or `&_version=2`, if there is a question mark in the URL already) to all URLs.

This will have no effect on your web application (unless it uses the _version GET field), but simulate changed URLs all linked resources. Since the initial URL (say, `/`) will always be requested, this will make any browser redownload all resources.

Comment: Whilst this kind of bust would work for files such as CSS and JS, if the HTML was being re-downloaded on each request. IE (I've tested 6-8 so far) doesn't seem to re-request the HTML that it has cached. Perhaps its a 'behind-a-proxy' issue, but I've known IE to cache like Jon Skeet's brain - so I'm thinking its more of a browser issue

Comment: PS - Also tried an IIS rewrite rule - to append a querystring. But because the browser isn't re-requesting the headers for the URL it doesn't see the `Location` header to do a redirect with. PS - if you DO use a query parameter with your URLs - be sure to update Google/Bing Webmaster Tools so that they don't list your querystring-appended URL :)